# Abusing the algebra of algebraic data types - why does this work?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, algebraic-data-types, miranda

The 'algebraic' expression for algebraic data types looks very suggestive to someone with a background in mathematics. Let me try to explain what I mean.

Having defined the basic types

- Product `•`
- Union `+`
- Singleton `X`
- Unit `1`

and using the shorthand `X²` for `X•X` and `2X` for `X+X` et cetera, we can then define algebraic expressions for e.g. linked lists

`data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)` ↔ `L = 1 + X • L`

and binary trees:

`data Tree a = Nil | Branch a (Tree a) (Tree a)` ↔ `T = 1 + X • T²`

Now, my first instinct as a mathematician is to go nuts with these expressions, and try to solve for `L` and `T`. I could do this through repeated substitution, but it seems much easier to abuse the notation horrifically and pretend I can rearrange it at will. For example, for a linked list:

`L = 1 + X • L`

`(1 - X) • L = 1`

`L = 1 / (1 - X) = 1 + X + X² + X³ + ...`

where I've used the power series expansion of `1 / (1 - X)` in a totally unjustified way to derive an interesting result, namely that an `L` type is either `Nil`, or it contains 1 element, or it contains 2 elements, or 3, etc.

It gets more interesting if we do it for binary trees:

`T = 1 + X • T²`

`X • T² - T + 1 = 0`

`T = (1 - √(1 - 4 • X)) / (2 • X)`

`T = 1 + X + 2 • X² + 5 • X³ + 14 • X⁴ + ...`

again, using the power series expansion (done with [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281+-+sqrt%281-4x%29%29+%2F+%282x%29)). This expresses the non-obvious (to me) fact that there is only one binary tree with 1 element, 2 binary trees with two elements (the second element can be on the left or the right branch), 5 binary trees with three elements etc.

So my question is - what am I doing here? These operations seem unjustified (what exactly is the square root of an algebraic data type anyway?) but they lead to sensible results. does the quotient of two algebraic data types have any meaning in computer science, or is it just notational trickery?

And, perhaps more interestingly, is it possible to extend these ideas? Is there a theory of the algebra of types that allows, for example, arbitrary functions on types, or do types require a power series representation? If you can define a class of functions, then does composition of functions have any meaning?

Comment: I'm not sure if the result is correct for example a binary tree with 2 elements could have more than 2 forms.

Comment: Not if it stores data in every node. It either looks like `Branch x (Branch y Nil Nil) Nil` or it looks like `Branch x Nil (Branch y Nil Nil)`.

Comment: Amazing! — ...I though mathematicians never went nuts, except if _we physicists_ do horrible stuff like this?? — By the way, you forgot the `X` term in the geometric series expansion.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, it's just that mathematicians always have to clean up the mess the physicists make.  But we make our own mess sometimes too :-)

Comment: bottom (_|_) would be 0; correct? Funny, it even looks like a bottom when placed in parens. Also, how can you justify solving that equation when division and subtraction are not defined?

Comment: @nlucaroni: bottom is a value, not a type. A true zero type would have no values of that type whatsoever, which isn't possible in Haskell unless you ignore bottoms. If you do take bottom values into account, then types containing only bottoms become the unit type which is... not helpful most of the time, and lots of other stuff breaks as well.

Comment: *[Concrete Mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_Mathematics)* by Ronald Graham, Donald Knuth and Oren Patashnik is a good book that provides a lot of examples of uses of such formal series. It doesn't go deeply into the theoretical foundations though.

Comment: @C.A.McCann Bottom is a type (up to isomorphism), it just happens that bottom is "inhabited" in Haskell. This must be the case since bottom is clearly not a value (aka proof) in intuitionist logic, yet is a perfectly good proposition.  Either `data Bottom` or `type bottom = forall a, a` are perfectly reasonable encodings of the _type_ bottom and should be initial objects.  `error "bad"` is by no means the same thing as `bad = bad` even though these both are values that inhabit all types, which means treating bottom as a singular value doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @PhilipJF: `Bottom` is a reasonable name for that type, but "bottom" generally refers (collectively) to the least-defined value inhabiting each lifted type--the type you're talking about is more often called `Void` in Haskell. And as far as pure code is concerned, all bottoms are equivalent, so speaking of all bottoms as a single value is usually sensible enough, insofar as anything involving bottom is sensible.

Comment: I agree it is common Haskell practice, its still silly.  Namely, it means we use "bottom" differently then they do in logic and type theory which seams bad to me.  Looking the same from pure code doesn't make them the same: "Tackling the Awkward Squad" makes it clear that the semantics of Haskell has a whole host of "bad values"  of which looping forever and throwing an exception are clearly not the same.  Substituting one for the other is not valid equational reasoning.  Haskell has a vocabulary for describing these bad values `undefined`, `throw`, etc.  We should use it.

Comment: On further reflection, I guess that the Haskell communities (ab)use of the word "bottom" is actually kind of nice, since it makes clear the weakness of the logic, since "bottom" or "false" is a proof of every type... It also makes sense visually in trellis diagrams... We really should come up with a denotation semantics that matches the operational semantics by separating out the different "least-defined values".

Comment: Well, the term "bottom" in Haskell comes from Domain Theory, which is used in defining the semantics of lifted types. It's still an initial object, just in a completely different category than the ones we usually talk about in Haskell...

Comment: Good point: change the category and my correspondence between False and Bottom doesn't seem so important.  My quest to use bottom in its propositional meaning was misguided.  I freely admit to finding most of Scott totally incomprehensible, so excuse me if this is non helpful: my remaining concern is that a domain should only have one "bottom", while I think that it is clear that Haskell has several.  Having to treat all these values the same for the purpose of denotational semantics is ugly.  We should fix that.

Comment: @PhilipJF You may be interested in this paper by Simon Peyton Jones and others working on just that, a more precise denotational semantics for exceptions in a Haskell-like language that still provides a lot of flexibility for optimization. http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/imprecise-exn.htm

Comment: @DougMcClean thanks.  I think I skimmed that paper once but had entirely forgotten it.

Comment: My mind was blown by this question

Comment: @ChrisTaylor eagerly awaiting pt. 4 of your [series](http://chris-taylor.github.io/blog/2013/02/10/the-algebra-of-algebraic-data-types/) :)

Comment: This question reminders me of this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YScIPA8RbVE&feature=share , really great through out interpretation of a algebra of types.

Comment: @hack.augusto Not that surprising - I gave that talk about a year after I asked this question :)

Comment: @ChrisTaylor Oh wow, I really didn't pay attention to the dates, neither that you were author of both, thanks for the great talk ;D

Comment: @C.A.McCann I'd be interested to know how this could be formalized for existential quantification. For example, the type `forall a. a` has zero inhabitants. The type `forall a. a -> a` has one inhabitant (i.e. `id`). The type `forall a. (a -> a) -> a -> a` has infinite inhabitants (i.e. the natural numbers). Can you explain how the number of inhabitants of such existentially quantified types could be mechanically derived?

Comment: @AaditMShah: Can't think of anything off the top of my head, sorry. I'm not sure how higher-rank polymorphism would work either. I suspect the "algebra" analogy starts to break down pretty quickly.

Comment: @C.A.McCann I thought of something. For all the three universally quantified types that I mentioned earlier (I mistakenly wrote existentially quantified in my previous comment), they denote the [Mogensen-Scott encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mogensen%E2%80%93Scott_encoding) of data types in the lambda calculus. Hence, `forall a. a` is equivalent to `data Void`; and `forall a. a -> a` is equivalent to `data Unit = Unit`; and `forall a. (a -> a) -> a -> a` is equivalent to `data Nat = Succ Nat | Zero` for which `N = N + 1` and by substitution we get `N = ∑ (n to ∞) 1 = ∞`.

Comment: @AaditMShah: That's true, but doesn't really help with the general case. Unless there's some way to factor out the polymorphic component to get a Mogensen-Scott decoded type + the remainder of the original type?

Comment: @shang, could you please fix that link, if you still remember its content after 7 years?

Comment: The link to the Lab49 blog that @shang posted is no longer available, but the Wayback machine has a capture of the page: https://web.archive.org/web/20150905151956/http://blog.lab49.com/archives/3011

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Disclaimer: A lot of this doesn't really work quite right when you account for ⊥, so I'm going to blatantly disregard that for the sake of simplicity.

A few initial points:

- Note that "union" is probably not the best term for A+B here--that's specifically [a *disjoint* union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union) of the two types, because the two sides are distinguished even if their types are the same. For what it's worth, the more common term is simply "sum type".
- Singleton types are, effectively, all unit types. They behave identically under algebraic manipulations and, more importantly, the amount of information present is still preserved.
- You probably want a zero type as well. Haskell provides that as `Void`. There are no values whose type is zero, just as there is one value whose type is one.

There's still one major operation missing here but I'll get back to that in a moment.

As you've probably noticed, Haskell tends to borrow concepts from Category Theory, and all of the above has a very straightforward interpretation as such:

- Given objects A and B in **Hask**, their product A×B is the unique (up to isomorphism) type that allows two projections *fst* : A×B → A and *snd* : A×B → B, where given any type C and functions *f* : C → A, *g* : C → B you can define the pairing *f &&& g* : C → A×B such that *fst ∘ (f &&& g)* = *f* and likewise for *g*. Parametricity guarantees the universal properties automatically and my less-than-subtle choice of names should give you the idea. The `(&&&)` operator is defined in `Control.Arrow`, by the way.
- The dual of the above is the coproduct A+B with injections *inl* : A → A+B and *inr* : B → A+B, where given any type C and functions *f* : A → C, *g* : B → C, you can define the copairing *f ||| g* : A+B → C such that the obvious equivalences hold. Again, parametricity guarantees most of the tricky parts automatically. In this case, the standard injections are simply `Left` and `Right` and the copairing is the function `either`.

Many of the properties of product and sum types can be derived from the above. Note that any singleton type is a terminal object of **Hask** and any empty type is an initial object.

Returning to the aforementioned missing operation, in a [cartesian closed category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_closed_category) you have [exponential objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_object) that correspond to arrows of the category. Our arrows are functions, our objects are types with kind `*`, and the type `A -> B` indeed behaves as B<sup>A</sup> in the context of algebraic manipulation of types. If it's not obvious why this should hold, consider the type `Bool -> A`. With only two possible inputs, a function of that type is isomorphic to two values of type `A`, i.e. `(A, A)`. For `Maybe Bool -> A` we have three possible inputs, and so on. Also, observe that if we rephrase the copairing definition above to use algebraic notation, we get the identity C<sup>A</sup> × C<sup>B</sup> = C<sup>A+B</sup>.

As for *why* this all makes sense--and in particular why your use of the power series expansion is justified--note that much of the above refers to the "inhabitants" of a type (i.e., distinct values having that type) in order to demonstrate the algebraic behavior. To make that perspective explicit:

- The product type `(A, B)` represents a value each from `A` and `B`, taken independently. So for any fixed value `a :: A`, there is one value of type `(A, B)` for each inhabitant of `B`. This is of course the cartesian product, and the number of inhabitants of the product type is the product of the number of inhabitants of the factors.
- The sum type `Either A B` represents a value from either `A` or `B`, with the left and right branches distinguished. As mentioned earlier, this is a disjoint union, and the number of inhabitants of the sum type is the sum of the number of inhabitants of the summands.
- The exponential type `B -> A` represents a mapping from values of type `B` to values of type `A`. For any fixed argument `b :: B`, any value of `A` can be assigned to it; a value of type `B -> A` picks one such mapping for each input, which is equivalent to a product of as many copies of `A` as `B` has inhabitants, hence the exponentiation.

While it's tempting at first to treat types as sets, that doesn't actually work very well in this context--we have disjoint union rather than the standard union of sets, there's no obvious interpretation of intersection or many other set operations, and we don't usually care about set membership (leaving that to the type checker).

On the other hand, the constructions above spend a lot of time talking about *counting* inhabitants, and *enumerating* the possible values of a type is a useful concept here. That quickly leads us to [enumerative combinatorics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerative_combinatorics), and if you consult the linked Wikipedia article you'll find that one of the first things it does is define "pairs" and "unions" in exactly the same sense as product and sum types by way of [generating functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function), then does the same for "sequences" that are identical to Haskell's lists using exactly the same technique you did.

---

**Edit:** Oh, and here's a quick bonus that I think demonstrates the point strikingly. You mentioned in a comment that for a tree type `T = 1 + T^2` you can derive the identity `T^6 = 1`, which is clearly wrong. However, `T^7 = T` *does* hold, and a bijection between trees and seven-tuples of trees can be constructed directly, cf. [Andreas Blass's "Seven Trees in One"](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~ablass/comb.html).

**Edit×2:** On the subject of the "derivative of a type" construction mentioned in other answers, you might also enjoy [this paper from the same author](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/~conor/Dissect.pdf) which builds on the idea further, including notions of division and other interesting whatnot.

Comment: This is a great explanation, particularly as a jumping-off point into things like http://strictlypositive.org/diff.pdf

Comment: @acfoltzer: Thanks! :] And yes, that's a great paper that develops these ideas. You know, I think at least 5% of my total reputation on SO can be attributed to "helping people understand one of Conor McBride's papers"...

Comment: Question about the T^7 case - that paper specifically describes a “very explicit”, “particularly elementary” bijection, but why would those qualifiers matter for these equalities? Put another way, both T and T^n (where n is a constant) are countably infinite, so there exists a bijection between any pair of them, so why can we not say T=T^2=T^3=T^4=…etc. ?

Answer (score 53):

Binary trees are defined by the equation `T=1+XT^2` in the semiring of types. By construction, `T=(1-sqrt(1-4X))/(2X)` is defined by the same equation in the semiring of complex numbers. So given that we're solving the same equation in the same class of algebraic structure it actually shouldn't be surprising that we see some similarities.

The catch is that when we reason about polynomials in the semiring of complex numbers we typically use the fact that the complex numbers form a ring or even a field so we find ourselves using operations such as subtraction that don't apply to semirings. But we can often eliminate subtractions from our arguments if we have a rule that allows us to cancel from both sides of an equation. This is the kind of thing proved by [Fiore and Leinster](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0212377v1) showing that many arguments about rings can be transferred to semirings.

This means that lots of your mathematical knowledge about rings can be reliably transferred to types. As a result, some arguments involving complex numbers or power series (in the ring of formal power series) can carry over to types in a completely rigorous way.

However there's more to the story than this. It's one thing to prove two types are equal (say) by showing two power series are equal. But you can also deduce information about types by inspecting the terms in the power series. I'm not sure of what the formal statement here should be. (I recommend Brent Yorgey's [paper](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~byorgey/pub/species-pearl.pdf) on [combinatorial species](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_species) for some work that's closely related but species are *not* the same as types.)

What I find utterly mind blowing is that what you've discovered can be extended to calculus. Theorems about calculus can be transferred over to the semiring of types. In fact, even arguments about finite differences can be transferred over and you find that classical theorems from numerical analysis have interpretations in type theory.

Have fun!

Comment: This differentiation/one hole context stuff is pretty cool. Let's see if I have this straight. A pair, with algebraic representation `P = X^2`, has derivative `dP = X + X`, so `Either` is the one-hole context of pair. That's pretty cool. We could 'integrate' `Either` to get a pair too. But if we try to 'integrate' `Maybe` (with type `M = 1 + X`) then we need to have `\int M = X + X^2 / 2` which is nonsensical (what's half a type?) Does this mean that `Maybe` isn't the one-hole context of any other type?

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: One-hole contexts preserve information about position inside products, i.e., `(A,A)` with a hole in it is an `A` and a bit telling you which side the hole is on. An `A` alone has no distinguished hole to fill in, which is why you can't "integrate" it. The type of the missing information in this case is, of course, `2`.

Comment: I've written about making sense of types like `X^2/2` http://blog.sigfpe.com/2007/09/type-of-distinct-pairs.html

Comment: @user207442, didn't you also do something about the bijection between one tree and seven trees? I linked to a paper about that in my answer but I could swear I remember first reading about it on your blog.

Comment: Calculus is just a new way of thinking about algebra.

Comment: @user207442 Do you have any links to papers on finite differences as applied to types, and the interpretation of theorems of numerical analysis in type theory? I've just finished reading the Brent Yorgey paper and another one by Conor McBride. Thoroughly enjoyed them, so hoping for some more like that!

Comment: @ChrisTaylor On finite (actually "divided") differences there's this: http://strictlypositive.org/CJ.pdf But at that point Conor didn't realise that he was describing differences. I wrote this though it may be tricky to follow: http://blog.sigfpe.com/2010/08/divided-differences-and-tomography-of.html I'd write a paper but I'm not very good at finishing them.

Answer (score 24):

It seems that all you're doing is expanding the recurrence relation.

```
L = 1 + X • L
L = 1 + X • (1 + X • (1 + X • (1 + X • ...)))
  = 1 + X + X^2 + X^3 + X^4 ...

T = 1 + X • T^2
L = 1 + X • (1 + X • (1 + X • (1 + X • ...^2)^2)^2)^2
  = 1 + X + 2 • X^2 + 5 • X^3 + 14 • X^4 + ...
```

And since the rules for the operations on the types work like the rules for arithmetic operations, you can use algebraic means to help you figure out how to expand the recurrence relation (since it is not obvious).

Comment: "Since the rules for the operations on the types work like the rules for arithmetic operations..." -- they don't, though. There's no notion of subtraction of types, let alone division and square roots.

So I guess my question is: when can you go from an algebraic manipulation assuming `X` is an element of the real numbers to a true statement about types, and moreover, where the does the correspondence (coefficient of `n`th degree term) <=> (number of types holding `n` elements) come from?

Comment: For example, from the expression for a Tree (`T = 1 + T^2`) I can derive `T^6 = 1` (i.e. solutions to `x^2 - x + 1 = 0` are sixth roots of unity) but it's clearly *not* true that a product type consisting of six binary trees is equivalent to the unit `()`.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor, but there is something happening there, as there *is* an isomorphism between `T^7` and `T`.  cf. http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9405205

Comment: @ChrisTaylor, here's something to think about.  When you add new algebraic operations, you hope not to break the properties of existing ones.  If you can come to the same answer two different ways, they ought to agree.  Therefore, providing there is *any representation at all* for `L = 1 + X * L`, it had better be the same one that you get when you series expand, by consistency.  Otherwise you could run the result backwards to get something false about the reals.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor There is indeed a notion of division of types, search for "Quotient Types" for more information. Whether it corresponds well with polynomial division, I don't know. It happens to be fairly impractical, imho, but it is out there.

Answer (score 24):

### Calculus and Maclaurin series with types

Here is another minor addition - a combinatorial insight into why the coefficients in a series expansion should 'work', in particular focusing on series which can be derived using the [Taylor-Maclaurin](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) approach from calculus. NB: the example series expansion you give of the manipulated list type is a Maclaurin series.

Since other answers and comments deal with the behaviour of algebraic type expressions (sums, products and exponents), this answer will elide that detail and focus on type 'calculus'.

You may notice inverted commas doing some heavy lifting in this answer. There are two reasons:

- we are in the business of giving interpretations from one domain to entities from another and it seems appropriate to delimit such such foreign notions in this way.
- some notions will be able to be formalised more rigorously, but the shape and ideas seem more important (and take less space to write) than the details.

### Definition of Maclaurin series

The [Maclaurin series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) of a function `f : ℝ → ℝ` is defined as

```
f(0) + f'(0)X + (1/2)f''(0)X² + ... + (1/n!)f⁽ⁿ⁾(0)Xⁿ + ...
```

where `f⁽ⁿ⁾` means the `n`th derivative of `f`.

To be able to make sense of the Maclaurin series as interpreted with types, we need to understand how we can interpret three things in a type context:

- a (possibly multiple) derivative
- applying a function to `0`
- terms like `(1/n!)`

and it turns out that these concepts from analysis have suitable counterparts in the type world.

What do I mean by a 'suitable counterpart'? It should have the flavour of an isomorphism - if we can preserve truth in both directions, facts derivable in one context can be transferred to the other.

### Calculus with types

So what does the derivative of a type expression mean? It turns out that for a large and well-behaved ('differentiable') class of type expressions and functors, there is a natural operation which behaves similarly enough to be a suitable interpretation!

To spoil the punchline, the operation analogous to differentiation is that of making 'one-hole contexts'. [This](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Zippers#Mechanical_Differentiation) is an excellent place to expand on this particular point further but the basic concept of a one-hole context (`da/dx`) is that it represents the result of extracting a single subitem of a particular type (`x`) from a term (of type `a`), preserving all other information, including that necessary to determine the original location of the subitem. For example, one way to represent a one-hole context for a list is with two lists: one for items which came before the extracted one, and one for items which came after.

The motivation for identifying this operation with differentiation comes from the following observations. We write `da/dx` to mean the type of one-hole contexts for type `a` with hole of type `x`.

```
d1/dx = 0
dx/dx = 1
d(a + b)/dx = da/dx + db/dx
d(a × b)/dx = a × db/dx + b × da/dx
d(g(f(x))/dx = d(g(y))/dy[f(x)/a] × df(x)/dx
```

Here, `1` and `0` represent types with exactly one and exactly zero inhabitants, respectively, and `+` and `×` represent sum and product types as usual. `f` and `g` are used to represent type functions, or type expression formers, and `[f(x)/a]` means the operation of substituting `f(x)` for every `a` in the preceding expression.

This may be written in a point-free style, writing `f'` to mean the derivative function of type function `f`, thus:

```
(x ↦ 1)' = x ↦ 0
(x ↦ x)' = x ↦ 1
(f + g)' = f' + g'
(f × g)' = f × g' + g × f'
(g ∘ f)' = (g' ∘ f) × f'
```

which may be preferable.

NB the equalities can be made rigorous and exact if we define derivatives using isomorphism classes of types and functors.

*Now, we notice in particular that the rules in calculus pertaining to the algebraic operations of addition, multiplication and composition (often called the Sum, Product and Chain rules) are reflected exactly by the operation of 'making a hole'. Further, the base cases of 'making a hole' in a constant expression or the term`x` itself also behave as differentiation, so by induction we get differentiation-like behaviour for all algebraic type expressions.*

Now we can interpret differentiation, what does the `n`th 'derivative' of a type expression, `dⁿe/dxⁿ` mean? It is a type representing `n`-place contexts: terms which, when 'filled' with `n` terms of type `x` yield an `e`. There is another key observation related to '`(1/n!)`' coming later.

### The invariant part of a type functor: applying a function to 0

We already have an interpretation for `0` in the type world: an empty type with no members. What does it mean, from a combinatorial point of view, to apply a type function to it? In more concrete terms, supposing `f` is a type function, what does `f(0)` look like? Well, we certainly don't have access to anything of type `0`, so any constructions of `f(x)` which require an `x` are unavailable. What is left is those terms which are accessible in their absence, which we can call the 'invariant' or 'constant' part of the type.

For an explicit example, take the `Maybe` functor, which can be represented algebraically as `x ↦ 1 + x`. When we apply this to `0`, we get `1 + 0` - it's just like `1`: the only possible value is the `None` value. For a list, similarly, we get just the term corresponding to the empty list.

When we bring it back and interpret the type `f(0)` as a number it can be thought of as the *count* of how many terms of type `f(x)` (for any `x`) can be obtained without access to an `x`: that is, the number of 'empty-like' terms.

### Putting it together: complete interpretation of a Maclaurin series

I'm afraid I can't think of an appropriate direct interpretation of `(1/n!)` as a type.

If we consider, though, the type `f⁽ⁿ⁾(0)` in light of the above, we see that it can be interpreted as the type of `n`-place contexts for a term of type `f(x)` which *do not already contain an* `x` - that is, when we 'integrate' them `n` times, the resulting term has *exactly* `n` `x`s, no more, no less. Then the interpretation of the type `f⁽ⁿ⁾(0)` as a number (as in the coefficients of the Maclaurin series of `f`) is simply a count of how many such empty `n`-place contexts there are. We are nearly there!

But where does `(1/n!)` end up? Examining the process of type 'differentiation' shows us that, when applied multiple times, it preserves the 'order' in which subterms are extracted. For example, consider the term `(x₀, x₁)` of type `x × x` and the operation of 'making a hole' in it twice. We get both sequences

```
(x₀, x₁)  ↝  (_₀, x₁)  ↝  (_₀, _₁)
(x₀, x₁)  ↝  (x₀, _₀)  ↝  (_₁, _₀)
(where _ represents a 'hole')
```

even though both come from the same term, because there are `2! = 2` ways to take two elements from two, preserving order. In general, [there are `n!`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) ways to take `n` elements from `n`. So in order to get a count of the number of configurations of a functor type which have `n` elements, we have to count the type `f⁽ⁿ⁾(0)` and divide by `n!`, *exactly* as in the coefficients of the Maclaurin series.

So dividing by `n!` turns out to be interpretable simply as itself.

### Final thoughts: 'recursive' definitions and analyticity

First, some observations:

- if a function f : ℝ → ℝ has a derivative, this derivative is unique
- similarly, if a function f : ℝ → ℝ is analytic, it has exactly one corresponding polynomial series

Since we have the chain rule, we can use [implicit differentiation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function#Implicit_differentiation), if we formalise type derivatives as isomorphism classes. But implicit differentiation doesn't require any alien manoeuvres like subtraction or division! So we can use it to analyse recursive type definitions. To take your list example, we have

```
L(X) ≅ 1 + X × L(X)
L'(X) = X × L'(X) + L(X)
```

and then we can evaluate

```
L'(0) = L(0) = 1
```

to obtain the coefficient of `X¹` in the Maclaurin series.

But since we are confident that these expressions are indeed strictly 'differentiable', if only implicitly, and since we have the correspondence with functions ℝ → ℝ, where derivatives are certainly unique, we can rest assured that even if we obtain the values using 'illegal' operations, the result is valid.

Now, similarly, to use the second observation, due to the correspondence (is it a homomorphism?) with functions ℝ → ℝ, we know that, provided we are satisfied that a function *has* a Maclaurin series, if we can find *any series at all*, the principles outlined above can be applied to make it rigorous.

As for your question about composition of functions, I suppose the chain rule provides a partial answer.

I'm not certain how many Haskell-style ADTs this applies to, but I suspect it is many if not all. I have discovered a truly marvellous proof of this fact, but this margin is too small to contain it...

Now, certainly this is only one way to work out what is going on here and there are probably many other ways.

### Summary: TL;DR

- type 'differentiation' corresponds to '[making a hole](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Zippers#Mechanical_Differentiation)'.
- applying a functor to `0` gets us the 'empty-like' terms for that functor.
- [Maclaurin](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) power series therefore (somewhat) rigorously correspond to enumerating the number of members of a functor type with a certain number of elements.
- [implicit differentiation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function#Implicit_differentiation) makes this more watertight.
- uniqueness of derivatives and uniqueness of power series mean we can fudge the details and it works.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative. If X and Y are vector spaces and f:X -> Y is a function, the 'type' of the derivative is Df:X -> L(X,Y), where L(X,Y) is the space of linear transformations from X to Y.

Answer (score 19):

I don't have a complete answer, but these manipulations tend to 'just work'. A relevant paper might be [Objects of Categories as Complex Numbers by Fiore and Leinster](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0212377v1) - I came across that one while reading [sigfpe's blog on a related subject](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2007/09/arboreal-isomorphisms-from-nuclear.html) ; the rest of that blog is a goldmine for similar ideas and is worth checking out!

You can also differentiate datatypes, by the way - that will get you the appropriate Zipper for the datatype!

Comment: The [Zipper trick](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Zippers#Mechanical_Differentiation) is awesome. I wish I understood it.

Comment: You can also make [zippers in Scheme](http://okmij.org/ftp/Scheme/zipper-in-scheme.txt) using delimited continuations, which allows you to derive them generically.

Answer (score 10):

The Algebra of Communicating Processes (ACP) deals with similar kinds of expressions for processes.
It offers addition and multiplication as operators for choice and sequence, with associated neutral elements.
Based on these there are operators for other constructs, such as parallelism and disruption.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_Communicating_Processes. There is also a paper online named "A Brief History of Process Algebra".

I am working on extending programming languages with ACP. Last April I presented a research paper at Scala Days 2012, available at http://code.google.com/p/subscript/

At the conference I demonstrated a debugger running a parallel recursive specification of a bag:

Bag = A; (Bag&a)

where A and a stand for input and output actions; the semicolon and ampersand stand for sequence and parallelism. See the video at SkillsMatter, reachable from the previous link.

A bag specification more comparable to

L = 1 + X•L

would be

B = 1 + X&B

ACP defines parallelism in terms of choice and sequence using axioms; see the Wikipedia article. I wonder what the bag analogy would be for

L = 1 / (1-X)

ACP style programming is handy for text parsers and GUI controllers. Specifications such as

searchCommand = clicked(searchButton) + key(Enter)

cancelCommand = clicked(cancelButton) + key(Escape)

may be written down more concisely by making the two refinements "clicked" and "key" implicit (like what Scala allows with functions). Hence we can write:

searchCommand = searchButton + Enter

cancelCommand = cancelButton + Escape

The right hand sides now contains operands that are data, rather than processes. At this level it is not necessary needed to know what implicit refinements will turn these operands into processes; they would not necessarily refine into input actions; output actions would also apply, e.g. in the specification of a test robot.

Processes get this way data as companions; thus I coin the term "item algebra".

Answer (score 10):

### Dependent type theory and 'arbitrary' type functions

My first answer to this question was high on concepts and low on details and reflected on the subquestion, 'what is going on?'; this answer will be the same but focused on the subquestion, 'can we get arbitrary type functions?'.

One extension to the algebraic operations of sum and product are the so called 'large operators', which represent the sum and product of a sequence (or more generally, the sum and product of a function over a domain) usually written `Σ` and `Π` respectively. See [Sigma Notation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Capital-sigma_notation).

So the sum

```
a₀ + a₁X + a₂X² + ...
```

might be written

```
Σ[i ∈ ℕ]aᵢXⁱ
```

where `a` is some sequence of real numbers, for example. The product would be represented similarly with `Π` instead of `Σ`.

When you look from a distance, this kind of expression looks a lot like an 'arbitrary' function in `X`; we are limited of course to expressible series, and their associated analytic functions. Is this a candidate for a representation in a type theory? Definitely!

The class of type theories which have immediate representations of these expressions is the class of 'dependent' type theories: theories with dependent types. Naturally we have terms dependent on terms, and in languages like Haskell with type functions and type quantification, terms and types depending on types. In a dependent setting, we additionally have types depending on terms. Haskell is not a dependently typed language, although many features of dependent types can be simulated [by torturing the language a bit](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.22.2636).

### Curry-Howard and dependent types

The 'Curry-Howard isomorphism' started life as an observation that the terms and type-judging rules of simply-typed lambda calculus correspond exactly to natural deduction (as formulated by Gentzen) applied to intuitionistic propositional logic, with types taking the place of propositions, and terms taking the place of proofs, despite the two being independently invented/discovered. Since then, it has been a huge source of inspiration for type theorists. One of the most obvious things to consider is whether, and how, this correspondence for propositional logic can be extended to predicate or higher order logics. Dependent type theories initially arose from this avenue of exploration.

For an introduction to the Curry-Howard isomorphism for simply-typed lambda calculus, see [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence#Natural_deduction_and_lambda_calculus). As an example, if we want to prove `A ∧ B` we must prove `A` and prove `B`; a combined proof is simply a pair of proofs: one for each conjunct.

In natural deduction:

```
Γ ⊢ A    Γ ⊢ B
Γ ⊢ A ∧ B
```

and in simply-typed lambda calculus:

```
Γ ⊢ a : A    Γ ⊢ b : B
Γ ⊢ (a, b) : A × B
```

Similar correspondences exist for `∨` and sum types, `→` and function types, and the various elimination rules.

An unprovable (intuitionistically false) proposition corresponds to an uninhabited type.

With the analogy of types as logical propositions in mind, we can start to consider how to model predicates in the type-world. There are many ways in which this has been formalised (see [this introduction](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory-intuitionistic/) to Martin-Löf's Intuitionistic Type Theory for a widely-used standard) but the abstract approach usually observes that a predicate is like a proposition with free term variables, or, alternatively, a function taking terms to propositions. If we allow type expressions to contain terms, then a treatment in lambda calculus style immediately presents itself as a possibility!

Considering only constructive proofs, what constitutes a proof of `∀x ∈ X.P(x)`? We can think of it as a proof function, taking terms (`x`) to proofs of their corresponding propositions (`P(x)`). So members (proofs) of the type (proposition) `∀x : X.P(x)` are 'dependent functions', which for each `x` in `X` give a term of type `P(x)`.

What about `∃x ∈ X.P(x)`? We need any member of `X`, `x`, together with a proof of `P(x)`. So members (proofs) of the type (proposition) `∃x : X.P(x)` are 'dependent pairs': a distinguished term `x` in `X`, together with a term of type `P(x)`.

Notation:
I will use

```
∀x ∈ X...
```

for actual statements about members of the class `X`, and

```
∀x : X...
```

for type expressions corresponding to universal quantification over type `X`. Likewise for `∃`.

### Combinatorial considerations: products and sums

As well as the Curry-Howard correspondence of types with propositions, we have the combinatorial correspondence of algebraic types with numbers and functions, which is the main point of this question. Happily, this can be extended to the dependent types outlined above!

I will use the modulus notation

```
|A|
```

to represent the 'size' of a type `A`, to make explicit the correspondence outlined in the question, between types and numbers. Note that this is a concept outside of the theory; I do not claim that there need be any such operator within the language.

Let us count the possible (fully reduced, canonical) members of type

```
∀x : X.P(x)
```

which is the type of dependent functions taking terms `x` of type `X` to terms of type `P(x)`. Each such function must have an output for every term of `X`, and this output must be of a particular type. For each `x` in `X`, then, this gives `|P(x)|` 'choices' of output.

The punchline is

```
|∀x : X.P(x)| = Π[x : X]|P(x)|
```

which of course doesn't make huge deal of sense if `X` is `IO ()`, but is applicable to algebraic types.

Similarly, a term of type

```
∃x : X.P(x)
```

is the type of pairs `(x, p)` with `p : P(x)`, so given any `x` in `X` we can construct an appropriate pair with any member of `P(x)`, giving `|P(x)|` 'choices'.

Hence,

```
|∃x : X.P(x)| = Σ[x : X]|P(x)|
```

with the same caveats.

This justifies the common notation for dependent types in theories using the symbols `Π` and `Σ`, and indeed many theories blur the distinction between 'for all' and 'product' and between 'there is' and 'sum', due to the above-mentioned correspondences.

We are getting close!

### Vectors: representing dependent tuples

Can we now encode numerical expressions like

```
Σ[n ∈ ℕ]Xⁿ
```

as type expressions?

Not quite. While we can informally consider the meaning of expressions like `Xⁿ` in Haskell, where `X` is a type and `n` a natural number, it's an abuse of notation; this is a type expression containing a number: distinctly *not* a valid expression.

On the other hand, with dependent types in the picture, types containing numbers is precisely the point; in fact, dependent tuples or 'vectors' are a very commonly-cited example of how dependent types can provide [pragmatic type-level safety for operations like list access](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/konn/prove-your-haskell-for-great-safety/dependent-types-in-haskell). A vector is just a list along with type-level information regarding its length: precisely what we are after for type expressions like `Xⁿ`.

For the duration of this answer, let

```
Vec X n
```

be the type of length-`n` vectors of `X`-type values.

Technically `n` here is, rather than an *actual* natural number, a representation in the system of a natural number. We can represent natural numbers (`Nat`) in Peano style as either zero (`0`) or the successor (`S`) of another natural number, and for `n ∈ ℕ` I write `˻n˼` to mean the term in `Nat` which represents `n`. For example, `˻3˼` is `S (S (S 0))`.

Then we have

```
|Vec X ˻n˼| = |X|ⁿ
```

for any `n ∈ ℕ`.

### Nat types: promoting ℕ terms to types

Now we can encode expressions like

```
Σ[n ∈ ℕ]Xⁿ
```

as types. This particular expression would give rise to a type which is of course isomorphic to the type of lists of `X`, as identified in the question. (Not only that, but from a category-theoretic point of view, the type function - which is a functor - taking `X` to the above type is [*naturally* isomorphic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation) to the List functor.)

One final piece of the puzzle for 'arbitrary' functions is how to encode, for

```
f : ℕ → ℕ
```

expressions like

```
Σ[n ∈ ℕ]f(n)Xⁿ
```

so that we can apply arbitrary coefficients to a power series.

We already understand the correspondence of algebraic types with numbers, allowing us to map from types to numbers and type functions to numerical functions. We can also go the other way! - taking a natural number, there is obviously a definable algebraic type with that many term members, whether or not we have dependent types. We can easily prove this *outside* of the type theory by induction. What we need is a way to map from natural numbers to types, *inside* the system.

A pleasing realisation is that, once we have dependent types, proof by induction and construction by recursion become intimately similar - indeed they are the very same thing in many theories. Since we can prove by induction that types exist which fulfil our needs, should we not be able to construct them?

There are several ways to represent types at the term level. I will use here an imaginary Haskellish notation with `*` for the universe of types, itself usually considered a type in a dependent setting.<sup>1</sup>

Likewise, there are also at least as many ways to notate '`ℕ`-elimination' as there are dependent type theories. I will use a Haskellish pattern-matching notation.

We need a mapping, `α` from `Nat` to `*`, with the property

```
∀n ∈ ℕ.|α ˻n˼| = n.
```

The following pseudodefinition suffices.

```
data Zero -- empty type
data Successor a = Z | Suc a -- Successor ≅ Maybe

α : Nat -> *
α 0 = Zero
α (S n) = Successor (α n)
```

So we see that the action of `α` mirrors the behaviour of the successor `S`, making it a kind of homomorphism. `Successor` is a type function which 'adds one' to the number of members of a type; that is, `|Successor a| = 1 + |a|` for any `a` with a defined size.

For example `α ˻4˼` (which is `α (S (S (S (S 0))))`), is

```
Successor (Successor (Successor (Successor Zero)))
```

and the terms of this type are

```
Z
Suc Z
Suc (Suc Z)
Suc (Suc (Suc Z))
```

giving us exactly four elements: `|α ˻4˼| = 4`.

Likewise, for any `n ∈ ℕ`, we have

```
|α ˻n˼| = n
```

as required.

1. *Many theories require that the members of `*` are mere representatives of types, and an operation is provided as an explicit mapping from terms of type `*` to their associated types. Other theories permit the literal types themselves to be term-level entities.*

### 'Arbitrary' functions?

Now we have the apparatus to express a fully general power series as a type!

The series

```
Σ[n ∈ ℕ]f(n)Xⁿ
```

becomes the type

```
∃n : Nat.α (˻f˼ n) × (Vec X n)
```

where `˻f˼ : Nat → Nat` is some suitable representation within the language of the function `f`. We can see this as follows.

```
|∃n : Nat.α (˻f˼ n) × (Vec X n)|
    = Σ[n : Nat]|α (˻f˼ n) × (Vec X n)|          (property of ∃ types)
    = Σ[n ∈ ℕ]|α (˻f˼ ˻n˼) × (Vec X ˻n˼)|        (switching Nat for ℕ)
    = Σ[n ∈ ℕ]|α ˻f(n)˼ × (Vec X ˻n˼)|           (applying ˻f˼ to ˻n˼)
    = Σ[n ∈ ℕ]|α ˻f(n)˼||Vec X ˻n˼|              (splitting product)
    = Σ[n ∈ ℕ]f(n)|X|ⁿ                           (properties of α and Vec)
```

Just how 'arbitrary' is this? We are limited not only to integer coefficients by this method, but to natural numbers. Apart from that, `f` can be anything at all, given a [Turing Complete](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) language with dependent types, we can represent any analytic function with natural number coefficients.

I haven't investigated the interaction of this with, for example, the case provided in the question of `List X ≅ 1/(1 - X)` or what possible sense such negative and non-integer 'types' might have in this context.

Hopefully this answer goes some way to exploring how far we can go with arbitrary type functions.