# Function Types Bound to Arguments

Tags: haskell

Brent Yorgey's excellent [UPenn Haskell course](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/lectures/10-applicative.html) presents:

```
fmap2 :: Functor f => (a -> b -> c) -> (f a -> f b -> f c)
fmap2 h fa fb = undefined
```

The types of `h`, `fa` and `fb` break down to:

```
h  :: a -> b -> c
fa :: f a
fb :: f b
```

It's not clear to me why `h` refers to the entire function `(a -> b -> c)`.

Why couldn't `h` refer to `a` and `fa` refer to `(b -> c)`?

Do the parentheses in `(a -> b -> c)` make the difference?

**EDIT**

Consider [leftaroundabout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/745903/leftaroundabout)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27631384/function-types-bound-to-arguments#comment43694000_27631384):

> For anyone just reading this without knowing the particular course referred to: `fmap2` can not be defined with that signature.
>
> It actually needs to be `liftA2 :: Applicative a => (a->b->c) -> (f a->f b->f c)`

Comment: For anyone just reading this without knowing the particular course referred to: `fmap2` can _not_ be defined with that signature. It actually needs to be `liftA2 :: Applicative a => (a->b->c) -> (f a->f b->f c)`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, the parentheses make the difference exactly as you say. Because `(->)` is [right-associative](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Operator_associativity&oldid=637783652#A_detailed_example), but not [mathematically associative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property), a parenthesized expression on the left side of a function arrow cannot be split up the way you're suggesting:

```
(a -> b) -> (f a -> f b) /= a -> b -> f a -> f b
```

The `->` operator is in this regard just like the exponentiation operator, `^`, which is notationally right-associative but [not mathematically associative](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Associative_property&oldid=634439998#Non-associativity):

```
(2 ^ 2) ^ (2 ^ 2) /= 2 ^ 2 ^ 2 ^ 2
4       ^ 4       /= 2 ^ (2 ^ (2 ^ 2))
256               /= 2 ^ (2 ^ 4)
256               /= 2 ^ 16
256               /= 65536
```

(The analogy to exponentiation isn't my own invention; function types are "exponential types" in the same sense that `(a, b)` is a "product type" and `Either a b` is a "sum type." But note that `a -> b` is analogous to `b ^ a`, not `a ^ b`. [See this blog post for an example-heavy explanation](http://chris-taylor.github.io/blog/2013/02/10/the-algebra-of-algebraic-data-types/); also [this answer gives a mathematical overview of type algebra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9197803/1186208).)

The apparent oddity with `fmap2` is that the type looks like it takes *one* parameter, but the definition looks like it takes *three*. Contrast this version, which to me at least looks more like the type signature:

```
fmap2 :: Functor f => (a -> b -> c) -> (f a -> f b -> f c)
fmap2 h = \fa fb -> undefined
```

Now we have a nice "one-argument" thing, `fmap2 h = ...`, with a "two-argument" lambda on the right. The trick is that in Haskell these two expressions are equivalent[*]: the [Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.4.3.1) says the "function" form, with the parameters on the LHS, is "semantically equivalent" to a simple pattern binding of a lambda.

You could also rewrite the type to eliminate the parentheses on the *right* side of an arrow, again because `->` is right-associative:

```
   (a -> b -> c) -> (f a -> f b -> f c) 
== (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
```

just like

```
   (2 ^ 2 ^ 2) ^ (2 ^ 2 ^ 2)
== (2 ^ 2 ^ 2) ^ 2 ^ 2 ^ 2
```

[*]: They're semantically equivalent, but when compiled with GHC their *performance* characteristics can and sometimes do differ. GHC's optimizer treats `f x = ...` and `f = \x -> ...` differently.