# Generalization of Exponential Type

Tags: haskell, category-theory, category-abstractions

How (if at all) does the exponential interpretation of `(->)` (`a -> b` as *b<sup>a</sup>*) generalize to categories other than Hask/Set? For example it would appear that the interpretation for the category of non-deterministic functions is roughly `Kliesli [] a b` as *2<sup>a * b</sup>* (`a -> b -> Bool`).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. Exponentials can be found in any cartesian closed category. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_closed_category

Comment: The exponential interpretation of `a -> b` is `b^a`. Consider `a -> ()` which has only `1^a=1` inhabitant, namely `const ()`. On the other hand, `() -> b` has `b^1=b` inhabitants, one for each inhabitant of `b`.

Comment: @chi Expand that a tiny bit -- basically just copy some definitions from Wikipedia -- and I'll upvote your answer.

Comment: @Cirdec - Do you know of an existing SO answer to that effect? I want to add a cross-reference to an unrelated answer of mine that touches on the subject. (This off-topic comment will self-destruct whenever I remember to destruct it.)

Comment: @ChristianConkle This answer contains a similar explanation http://stackoverflow.com/a/9197803/414413

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notion of exponential can be defined in general terms, beyond Hask/Set. A category with exponentials and products is called a [*cartesian closed category*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_closed_category). This is a key notion in theoretical computer science since each c.c. category is essentially a model of the typed lambda calculus.

Roughly, in a cartesian closed category for any pair of objects `a,b` there exist:

- a product object `(a * b)`, and
- an exponential object `(b^ab)`

with morphisms

- `eval : (b^a)*a -> b` (in Haskell:  `\(f,x) -> f x`, AKA apply)
- for any `f : (a*b)->c`, there exists `Lf : a -> (c^b)` (in Haskell: `curry f`)

satisfying the equation "they enjoy in the lambda calculus", i.e., if `f : (a*b)->c`, then:

- `f = (Lf * id_a) ; eval`

In Haskell, the last equation is:

- `f = \(x :: (a,b), y :: a) -> apply (curry f x, id y) where apply (g,z) = g z`

or, using arrows,

- `f = (curry f *** id) >>> apply where apply (g,z) = g z`