# Abusing the algebra of algebraic data types even further - why does this work?

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

So I have been reading, how you can convert ADTs into what resembles Real numbers and manipulating them, on pages like [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190352/) and [this 3 part series](http://chris-taylor.github.io/blog/2013/02/10/the-algebra-of-algebraic-data-types/) and [especially this](https://codewords.recurse.com/issues/three/algebra-and-calculus-of-algebraic-data-types).

The "Trouble" section of the last link caught my eyes and I tried to solve for `Nat` in it even though the article states it's impossible.

```
Nat = 1 + Nat
Nat - Nat = 1
Nat(1 - 1) = 1
Nat = 1 / (1 - 1)
```

This might seem like total nonsense since I just divided by 0 (and you might be right), but if you read any of those links or something similar, then you'll notice that it looks very similar to a definition of a list.

```
List(x) = 1 / (1 - x)
```

So you could write Nat like `Nat = List(1) = 1 + 1 + 1 + ...`, which is exactly what you would get by repeated substitution in the starting equation. This is also equivalent to defining Natural numbers like this in Haskell:

```
type Nat = [()]
```

Which is definitely a valid encoding of Natural numbers, where `0 = []` and `S(N) = () : N`.

---

So my question is how come did I get a valid result out of this? I just divided by zero. Not to mention the starting equation itself is pretty much a contradiction.

So how come I got something that makes sense at the end of this? Is this just pure coincidence or is the division by 0 somehow defined in this context that makes sense?

Comment: Strictly speaking, `1 != 1*1`, so it would be more correct to write `Nat = 1 + 1*1 + 1*1*1 + ...`.

Comment: @chepner can you please explain why? The way I understood it, types form a semiring, where `1` is the identity of `*`. In other words `x * 1 = 1` for any x. So `1` and `1*1` are equivalent.

Comment: They are *isomorphic*, not equivalent. The ordered pair `((), ())` is distinct from the `()`. `x * 1 == x` because you can losslessly convert a value `(a, ()) :: (x,())` to `a :: x` and vice versa.

Comment: @chepner, all these kinds of manipulations are (at best) up to isomorphism anyways. Just read `=` as "is isomorphic to" if you like.

Comment: I think the answer is probably that you only did manipulations that you also could have done with List(x), but writing 1 instead of x. But it's not clear to me that there is a real question here.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Nat` is infinite, you can't really use `Nat - Nat = Nat ⋅ (1 - 1) = Nat ⋅ 0 = 0`. The difference `Nat - Nat` is *some finite number*, as it were, whereas `Nat` is obviously infinite. So this `1 - 1` isn't really zero, it's rather like an infinitesimally small value in [nonstandard analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_analysis). If you divide something by an infinitesimal, you get something divergingly big (infinite, indeed... duh), but you don't exactly run into division-by zero.

In fact, I think that paradox you asked about could be seen as a “proof that `Nat` is infinite” – because if it were finite, you *would* be dividing by zero.

Except of course you can't really *prove* anything with this kind of type arithmetic... it's an entertaining pastime, but not really sound mathematics.

Comment: Not with this sort, no, but with more careful sorts (difference calculus stuff) you surely can.