# What's distributing a functor over a tuple called?

Tags: haskell, functor

Is there a name for this family of operations?

```
Functor f => f (a, b) -> (f a, f b)
Functor f => f (a, b, c) -> (f a, f b, f c)
...
Functor f => f (a, b, ..., z)  -> (f a, f b, ..., f z)
```

They're easy to implement, just trying to figure out what to call it.

```
\fab -> (fst <$> fab, snd <$> fab)
```

For me, it came up in the context of `f ~ (x ->)`.

Comment: I guess these are just in the opposite direction as `uncurry (liftA2 (,)) :: Applicative f :: (f a, f b) -> f (a,b)`, so this might have something to do with [comonoidal functors](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/16264/20074)

Comment: also relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190352/abusing-the-algebra-of-algebraic-data-types-why-does-this-work

Answer (score 8):

In your specific context `f ~ (x ->)`, I think they can be called "power laws".

Indeed, in theory, it is common to write `A -> B` as the power `B^A`. The pair type `(A,B)` is also commonly written as a product `(A*B)`.

Your first law is then written as

```
(A*B)^C = A^C * B^C
```

and is a classic type isomorphism. This can be easily generalized to tuples in the obvious way.

In the general case, where `f` is an arbitrary functor, I can't think of nothing else than "distribution", right now.

Comment: See Chris Taylor's series starting here: http://chris-taylor.github.io/blog/2013/02/10/the-algebra-of-algebraic-data-types/

Answer (score 2):

There is `Data.Distributive` which is the dual of `Data.Traversable`. It provides the `distribute` function which can be specialized e.g. as `f (Stream a) -> Stream (f a)` or `distribute :: f (Vec n a) -> Vec n (f a)`. The latter example is a homogeneous variant of your family of functions.

But we can generalize `Data.Distributive` a bit just like lenses generalize functors. Enter `Colens`:

```
type Colens s t a b = forall f. Functor f => (f a -> b) -> f s -> t
```

Here is the mirror of [`Control.Lens.Each`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/Control-Lens-Each.html):

```
class Coeach s t a b | s -> a, t -> b, s b -> t, t a -> s where
  coeach :: Colens s t a b

instance (a~a', b~b') => Coeach (a,a') (b,b') a b where
  coeach f p = (f $ fst <$> p, f $ snd <$> p)

instance (a~a2, a~a3, b~b2, b~b3) => Coeach (a,a2,a3) (b,b2,b3) a b where
  coeach f p = ...

...
```

And just like with `each` we can iterate over tuples

```
each_id1 :: Applicative f => (f a, f a) -> f (a, a)
each_id1 = each id

each_id2 :: Applicative f => (f a, f a, f a) -> f (a, a, a)
each_id2 = each id
```

with `coeach` we can coiterate over tuples:

```
coeach_id1 :: Functor f => f (a, a) -> (f a, f a)
coeach_id1 = coeach id

coeach_id2 :: Functor f => f (a, a, a) -> (f a, f a, f a)
coeach_id2 = coeach id
```

This is still homogeneous, though. I don't know `lens` much, so can't say whether there is a heterogeneous `each` and the corresponding `coeach`.