# What type of algebraic data type is Option[T] or Optional<T>

Tags: functional-programming, algebraic-data-types

So it's my understanding there are two types of Algebraic Data Types (ADTs).  For the case of `Option[T]` in Scala or `Optional<T>` in Java, would this be an example of a sum type or a product type?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can figure it out if you consider that an `Optional<T>` is either a  `T` or no `T`.

Comment: Because it is fixed ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining the `Option[T]` type in Haskell makes it clear that it's a sum type.

```hs
data Option t = None | Some t
```

Values of type `Option t` can be one of 2 things:

1. `None`
2. `Some t`

So `Option[T]` and `Optional<T>` both take a type `T` and then add 1 more possible value (`None`).

---

For fun, we can also translate this ADT into an algebraic equation:

```
Option(t) = 1 + t
```

To see why, see this question: [Abusing the algebra of algebraic data types - why does this work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9190352/5743988)